# How do i get a/b?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

Consider the vectors $\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{w} = \begin{pmatrix} 3\\2 \end{pmatrix}$.

If the vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent, answer with $0$. If they aren't, find coefficients $a$ and $b$, not both $0$, such that
$a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}  + b \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$and answer with $\dfrac{a}{b}$.

I know that vectors v and w are not linearly  independent but im not sure how to get $\dfrac{a}{b}$.

Comment: How do we tell if two vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: You say they are parallel?

Comment: oops i just reallized they are linearly independent

Comment: Another clue is that if $\frac ab$ works, so does $\frac {2a}{2b}$.  As they presumably want a unique answer, it must be $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sequence of vectors $\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ are linearly independent if the equation

$$a\vec{v}+b\vec{w}=\vec{0}$$ 
is only satisfied by $a=b=0$. Therefore, we represent the vectors by the homogenuous linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3\\3&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

solving for $a$ and $b$ we find
$$\begin{cases} 
      a+3b=0\\
      3a+2b=0
   \end{cases}\implies \begin{cases} 
      a=-3b\\
      a=-\frac{2}{3}b
   \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} 
      a=0\\
      b=0
   \end{cases}$$

therefore the sequence of vectors $\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$a \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}  + b \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}.$This becomes the system of equations
\begin{align*} 
a + 3b &= 0, \\
3a + 2b &= 0.
\end{align*}The first equation gives $a = -3b$, and substituting that into the second equation gives
$3(-3b) + 2b = 0,$which becomes $-7b = 0$ and therefore, $b= 0$. Substituting back into the expression, we see that $a = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a+3b=0=3a+2b\implies b=2a$$